# Extract specific data from JavaScript .getAttribute()

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

So let's say I have this HTML link.

```
<a id="avId" href="http://www.whatever.com/user=74853380">Link</a>
```

And I have this JavaScript

```
av = document.getElementById('avId').getAttribute('href')
```

Which returns:

```
"http://www.whatever.com/user=74853380"
```

How do I extract `74853380` specifically from the resulting string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could do this.

1.) Using `substr` and `indexOf` to extract it

```
var str = "www.something.com/user=123123123";
str.substr(str.indexOf('=') + 1, str.length);
```

2.) Using regex

```
var str = var str = "www.something.com/user=123123123";
// You can make this more specific for your query string, hence the '=' and group
str.match(/=(\d+)/)[1];
```

You could also split on the `=` character and take the second value in the resulting array. Your best bet is probably regex since it is much more robust. Splitting on a character or using `substr` and `indexOf` is likely to fail if your query string becomes more complex. Regex can also capture multiple groups if you need it to.

Comment: Thank you for solving my issue, it works very well!

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could help :)

Comment: And if let's say at the end of the = instead of a digit I have a word? Like "Nick"?

Comment: Then you can just use `/=(\w+)/` as your regular expression instead. That will capture any alphanumeric string after the `=`. Off topic, but [this is a site](http://www.rubular.com/) I use to practice and prototype regular expressions. Really helped me. The reference there is a very small subset if what regex can do, but it is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression:

```
var exp = /\d+/;
var str = "http://www.whatever.com/user=74853380";
console.log(str.match(exp));
```

Explanation:

**/\d+/** - means "one or more digits"

Another case when you need find more than one number

```
"http://www.whatever.com/user=74853380/question/123123123"
```

You can use **g** flag.

```
var exp = /\d+/g;
var str = "http://www.whatever.com/user=74853380/question/123123123";
console.log(str.match(exp));
```

You can [play](http://regex101.com/) with regular expressions

Comment: This one works very well too. Since I need the number in another variable for later use, I can do `id = str.match(exp);`

Comment: @Marian Yes of course, you can use like that var id = str.match(exp)[0];

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could `split()` it for a one liner answer.

```
var x = parseInt(av.split("=")[1],10); //convert to int if needed
```

Comment: This doesn't work, what if an extra parameter is passed *before* `user`? Sorry bro. But while messy you could still split at `"user="` instead of just `"="`

Comment: Well there's a lot of "what ifs" that could happen, and the answer could be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: That's not good enough though. It's not only possible, it's *likely* that this will encounter problems and it's a poor, error-prone solution.
I know this question is pathetic haha but still